# Is it possible to run CSSLint from WSH on Windows?

Tags: css, wsh, csslint

There's a [CSSLint project on github](https://github.com/stubbornella/csslint). It appears to be philosophically inspired by the JSLINT/JSHINT project.  It's a JavaScript program that checks the syntax of CSS files, and throws errors or warnings.

There are versions for Rhino and Node. 
How can I run it from Windows Script Host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get [the version of csslint that is modified for use with WSH](http://jslint-for-wsh.googlecode.com/files/csslint-wsh.js).

It works like this:

```
C:\dev\html>cscript c:\bin\csslint-wsh.js --format=compiler style\basic.css

CSSLINT
style\basic.css(5,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h1) has already been defined.
h1           { font-size: 20pt }
style\basic.css(6,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h2) has already been defined.
h2           { font-size: 18pt; font-weight:bold; color: navy }
style\basic.css(7,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h3) has already been defined.
h3           { font-size: 16pt; font-weight:bold; color: #483d8b;}
style\basic.css(8,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h4) has already been defined.
h4           { font-size: 14pt; font-weight:bold; color:#C71585; margin-bottom:2px; }
style\basic.css(9,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h5) has already been defined.
h5           { font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold; color:#6495ED; margin-bottom:2px; }
style\basic.css(10,1) CSSLINT: warning: Heading (h6) has already been defined.
h6           { font-size: 10pt; font-weight:bold; color:navy }
style\basic.css(12,1) CSSLINT: warning: Element (td.head) is overqualified, just use .head without element name.
td.head      { font-size: 12pt; color: #c71585;   font-weight: bold; }
style\basic.css(39,4) CSSLINT: warning: Broken box model: using width with padding.
   width: 48%;
style\basic.css(44,4) CSSLINT: warning: Broken box model: using width with border.
   margin: 0.2em 0 0.2em 0;
```